# How to accept backslashes in raw input

Tags: python, optparse

I'm writing a little program with **optparse**. It should **format shellcode**.
The problem is, that python doesn't accept e.g "\x31" as argument and interpret it as "x31".
Of course it is possible to build a workarround.

But is there a way to work with an input like so?:

`python prog.py -t \x31\xCA`

print(args) => '\x31\xCA'

Comment: This is not a python problem. The shell you are using is interpreting the backslashes before they are being sent to the python interpreter. Use double backslashes.

Comment: But as i say. Is there a way I can just copy&paste the shellcode?

Comment: Use quotation marks: `python prog.py -t "\x31\xCA"`

Comment: This as an answer and I close the thread. Thx

Comment: @HansWurst in case nobody mentioned it, argparse seems to be the preferred trend over optparse. (If it were in argparse you'd tell ArgumentParser to specifically expect a type string as that positional/flag argument, that way the `"` quote signs would be automatically wrapped around the argument. There might be an equivalent option in optparse, I don't know specifically...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quotation marks: `python prog.py -t "\x31\xCA"`